# FX Average Forward Pricing

Tags: fx, derivatives, hedging, pricing, forward

Lookin for documentation on how to price FX Arithmetic Average Rate Forwards.
Couldn't find any info on textbooks.
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. __Hint__: Try writing the arithmetic average forward as a sum of forwards.